# Why doesn't Java ship with standard String utilities?

Tags: java

Why do I have to write what should be String.join in my code? Can I patch Java?

```
public static String join(String[] arg, String delim) {
    String ret = "";
    for(int i=0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        ret += arg[i];
        if(i != arg.length - 1) {
            ret += delim;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Done.

Comment: No comment on "why", but this is a very inefficient `join`. You should use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: You can use Apache Commons, which has these types of utility methods: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking what the creators of Java were thinking when they created it, which can not lead to true answers but rather guesswork and conjectures. This is not an appropriate question for SO.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I would say that in this case, you may as well trade in some theoretical inefficiency for ease of understanding. (I have a feeling the latest compilers may even compile this to use a StringBuilder anyway.)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You're probably right but there are good answers coming out of it.

Comment: [It's in Java 8](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-), which will be released in March 2014.  And no you cannot patch java.lang.String, because that would be an enormous security hole.

Comment: @VGR I solemnly swear that I would write in exploits for my use only!

Comment: @NeilCoffey In general I would agree, but (1) joining a large number of strings this way can end up wasting a *lot* of memory, and (2) StringBuilders are not difficult to read in any sense, and I'd rather any collaborator who didn't understand it would stop and figure it out. You may be right about the automatic optimization, however.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 stream API, you can write*:

```
String joined = Arrays.stream(arg).collect(joining(delim));
```

For example, this prints `a,b,c`:

```
String joined = Arrays.stream(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}).collect(joining(","));
System.out.println(joined);
```

<sub>* `joining` requires the following import: `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;`</sub>

Comment: Or, also in Java 8: `String joined = String.join(",", "a", "b", "c");`

Comment: @VGR much better indeed - thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

JDK does not provide but [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) classs, which does pretty much the same.